# Using DSCONFIGAD to bind computer objects to a specific OU using a FQ LDAP DN

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, organizational-unit

The DSCONFIGAD utility for OS X has a -OU parameter that allows one to generate and bind computer objects to a specified -OU via a FQ LDAP DN argument.  This is taken directly from Apple's DSCONFIGAD man page:

```
 -ou dn   The LDAP DN of the container to use for adding the computer.  If this is not specified, it
          will default to the container "CN=Computers" within the domain that was specified (e.g.,
          "CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=ads,DC=demo,DC=com"
```

I have tried the following formats:

```
dsconfigad -opt1 arg1 -opt2 arg2 ... -ou "OU=BIO,CN=MANAGED CLIENT    
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou "OU=BIO,OU=MANAGED\ CLIENT\ 
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou "OU=BIO,OU=MANAGED CLIENT    
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou "OU=BIO,CN=MANAGED\ CLIENT\    
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou "CN=BIO,CN=MANAGED CLIENT    
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou "CN=BIO,CN=MANAGED\ CLIENT\    
                                          SYSTEMS,DC=WORLD,DC=HEADQ,DC=PRATT,DC=COM"

                                     -ou  bio.managed client systems.world.headq.pratt.com

                                     -ou  bio.managed\ client\ systems.world.headq.pratt.com
```

...And I just cannot get it to generate computer objects in the BIO OU.  It will generate objects in the default CN=COMPUTERS container just fine, but I haven't gotten it to work anywhere else yet.  The command and every other option I input works just fine, as well, just not the -ou option.  I get an error back saying "Container does not exist".  But the BIO ou within the MANAGED CLIENT SYSTEMS container is present in Active Directory.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look to see if you already pre provisioned the computer (a.k.a. container)

Comment: @Matt Yes, the computer had been provisioned.  Although this issue was solved long ago it turn out to be just a simple syntax error.  I don't remember exactly what but I either had the container path wrong or had misused a quote.  In any event, thanks so much for taking the time to respond to this after it had been neglected for so long.